# Wold Representation for an ARMA (1,1)

Tags: self-study, arima

I have this ARMA(1,1) process where $\epsilon_t$ is the classical White Noise process

$$X_t=\epsilon_t +\alpha_{t-1}\epsilon_{t-1}+\theta_{t-1}X_{t-1}$$

and I have to write its Wold representation. Using the lag operator I get

$$\epsilon_t=\frac{1-\theta_{t-1}L}{1+\alpha_{t-1}L}X_{t}$$ Assuming the process is stationary and invertible, how can I recover the Wold representation?

Comment: In the Wold representation $X_t$ is expressed as an infinite weighted sum of the current and past innovations $\epsilon_t$. You should rearrange the polynomials in your equation since there you have the innovations as a sum of past values of $X_t$. In the definition of the ARIMA(1,1) process, move the terms depending on $X_t$ to one side of the equation and those depending on $\epsilon_t$ to the other, then use the lag operator $L$ as you did and solve for $X_t$ (leave $X_t$ alone on one side of the equation).

Comment: It seems there a type it should be X(t-1) on the right not X(t) of the first equation.

Comment: You may be interested in this [post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117519/).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the error @Cagdas Ozgenc. So if I revert the formula what should i get? I'm sorry I don't know exactly what the result should be

Comment: The common arrangements of terms is $X_t = \frac{\theta(L)}{\phi(L)} \epsilon_t$. 
See my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117519/) for details on the notation.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wold's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wold%27s_theorem) states that every covariance-stationary time series $X_T$ can be written as the sum of two time series, one deterministic and one stochastic. What we are searching for is something of the following form:

$$X_t = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \gamma^j \varepsilon_{t - j} +\eta_t .
$$

How can we achieve this if we are given the process $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} -\theta \varepsilon_{t-1} +\varepsilon_t?$ By substitution! Write

\begin{align*}
y_{t} =& \phi( \phi y_{t-2} - \theta\varepsilon_{t-2}+\varepsilon_{t-1}) - \theta \varepsilon_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t,\\
=& \phi^2 y_{t-2} - \phi\theta \varepsilon_{t-2} + \phi\varepsilon_{t-1} - \theta \varepsilon_{t-1} +\varepsilon_t,\\
=&\phi^2( \phi y_{t-3} - \theta\varepsilon_{t-3}+\varepsilon_{t-2}) - \phi\theta \varepsilon_{t-2} + \phi\varepsilon_{t-1} - \theta \varepsilon_{t-1} +\varepsilon_t,\\
\vdots&
\end{align*}

We see that a pattern emerges and that this process can be written as an infinite sum of error terms:

$$ y_t =  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\phi^{j-1} ( \phi - \theta)\varepsilon_{t-j} + \varepsilon_t.
$$

That is, we have rewritten the ARMA(1,1) as an MA($\infty$) process.