# Understanding ARMA Model calculations With an Example

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima

Considering an ARMA (2,2) Model:
$$x_t - \phi_1x_{t-1}-\phi_2x_{t-2}=a_t + \theta_1a_{t-1} +\theta_2a_{t-2}$$ where $a_t \sim NID(0, 1)$.

Suppose $x_t$ is causal i.e.

$$x_t= a_t + \sum^\infty_{j=1}\psi_ja_{t-j}$$

Calculate $\psi_j, j = 1,2,3,4,5,6$

I'm a little bit lots. What are these $\psi_j$'s representing and then what is the process to calculate them?

Comment: See the answer from javlacalle here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117519/how-to-write-an-ar2-stationary-process-in-the-wold-representation

Comment: @MattP https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117670/196841

Thanks for his answer, just having a little bit of trouble still, "The values of $\psi_i$ can be obtained equating the coefficients related to the same lags, $L_i$, from both sides of the last equation, $\psi(L)\phi(L) = \theta(L)$."

Don't really know what is meant by equating the coefficients related to the same lag. Would you be able to clarify a bit more?