# Wold Decomposition of an AR(2) process: Expanding a product of geometric series

Tags: time-series, decomposition

In the last step of this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117552/203000), the author writes that to obtain Wold Representation of an AR(2) process, you need to expand the geometric sequences in the fractions on the right hand side:

$X_{t}=\frac{1}{(1-\lambda_{1}L)}\frac{1}{(1-\lambda_{2}L)}\varepsilon_{t}$

After expanding the sequences I am stuck with the following:

$X_{t}=(1+\lambda_{1}L+\lambda_{1}^{2}L^{2}+...+\lambda_{1}^{n}L^{n})(1+\lambda_{2}L+\lambda_{2}^{2}L^{2}+...+\lambda_{2}^{n}L^{n})\varepsilon_{t}$

How can I get rid of the lag operators and get to the MA representation from here?

Answer (score 2):

You have a product of two (infinite-order) polynomials and you have to turn it into a single polynomial in "expanded form" by *collecting like-terms*.  Doing this in the present case gives the following moving-average characteristic polynomial:

$$\begin{align}
\lambda(L)
&= (1+\lambda_{1}L)^{-1} (1+\lambda_{2}L)^{-1} \\[12pt]
&= (1+\lambda_{1}L+\lambda_{1}^{2}L^{2}+...+\lambda_{1}^{n}L^{n})(1+\lambda_{2}L+\lambda_{2}^{2}L^{2}+...+\lambda_{2}^{n}L^{n}) \\[12pt]
&= 1 + (\lambda_1+\lambda_2) L + (\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_1 \lambda_2 + \lambda_2^2) L^2 + (\lambda_1^3 + \lambda_1^2 \lambda_2 + \lambda_1 \lambda_2^2 + \lambda_2^3) L^3 + \cdots \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \Bigg( \sum_{j=0}^i \lambda_1^{i-j} \lambda_2^j \Bigg) L^i. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Applying this to the time-series equation then gives the (infinite) MA representation:

$$\begin{align}
X_t 
= \lambda(L) \varepsilon_t
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \Bigg( \sum_{j=0}^i \lambda_1^{i-j} \lambda_2^j \Bigg) L^i \varepsilon_t \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \Bigg( \sum_{j=0}^i \lambda_1^{i-j} \lambda_2^j \Bigg) \varepsilon_{t-i}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$